# My variables do not want to be initialized

Tags: delphi

```
var
  iMath, iAfr: integer;
begin
  if cbMath.checked then
    iMath := sedMathf.value div sedmatho.value and iMath * sedmathm.value
  else
    sedAfrm.setfocus;
end;
```

My variables do not want to be initialized, how can I prevent this or fix this?

Comment: By debugging the code of course.

Comment: Which variable doesn't want to be initialized? And what should it be initialized to?

Comment: `iMath` is not initialized before you use it in the calculation of the value of `iMath`. Read the code. Where does the value of `iMath` come from when you use it in `and iMath * edmathm.value`?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set iMath to a value using iMath. The right hand side of your assignment is undefined.

Comment: But doesn't Delphi always assign a default value like '0'? so it should be defined, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Relinkvent: local variables are not initialized

Comment: Depends on the type, but most of them are not. Interfaces are a notable exception, and strings also have a valid value, although that doesn't always mean they are empty..

Comment: @Relinkvent: That is only true for **global** variables, not for local variables.